# How can I use font awesome icon in a menu item

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I need to use a [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) icon in a menu... The menu icon in a line and next line the menu name will come, There will be a background image for that menu.

Attaching the image what i need is :

[image]

HTML Code :

```
<div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li > <span class="fa fa-camera-retro"></span><br/>  <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                            <li >  <a href="#"> Rule </a> </li>
                            <li > <a href="#"> Lookup </a> </li>
                            <li > <a href="#"> Search </a> </li>
                            <li >  <a href="#"> Publish </a> </li>
                            <li > <a href="#"> Package </a> </li>
                            <li > <a href="#">Help</a>  </li>
                        </ul>


            </div>
```

CSS is :

```
    .menu
{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:180px;
    margin:30px 0 0 0;
    background:#00569D;
    min-height:40px;
    z-index:0;

}
.menu ul
{
padding:10px 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.menu ul li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:13px 15px;
    min-height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    -ms-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
        -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
        transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
        background: url("mainNavItem-BG.png") no-repeat;
        background-position: right -1px;
    border-right: 1px solid #0068bc;

}
.menu ul li:hover
    {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #00264e;
    background: url("mainNavHover-BG.png") repeat-x;
    }

.menu ul li span
    {

    color: #ffffff;
    line-height:0px !important;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:20px;
    }
.menu ul li a
    {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #00264e;
    }
.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a:current
    {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #00264e;
        background:#000;
    }
```

The Final result I got is :

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Srijith

Comment: can't you just use font:15px awsome; in your ccs file (.menu ul li a)? check w3schools (web)fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish nav with icons with smaller style codes. Code:

```
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Example is [here](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/Grbsk)